# Как сделать ограничения для перехода на url?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно запретить переход по URL.

***web.php***

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'oper', 'middleware'=>['role:oper']], function (){
  Route::get('operall', 'ApplicController@index');
  Route::get('operall/drivers', 'DriversController@index')->name('driver_page');
});
```

***middleware***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\User_roles;
use App\User;
use Route;

class OwnerMiddleware
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $user = new User;
    $current = $user->find(Auth::user()->id)->role;
    $current = $current->find($current->id)->roles;

    if($current->name != 'admin' ) {
      return redirect('/');

    }

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Есть 3 роли (админ, опер, клиент) нужно чтобы клиент не смог перейти на URL опера.

Comment: Уже не впервые вижу `$user->find(Auth::user()->id)->role;`, `$current->find($current->id)->roles;`. Откуда вы берете эту бессмыслицу, из какой инструкции?

Comment: `$request->user()` и `Auth::user()` - это текущий аутентифицированный пользователь. То есть не нужно его повторно искать. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#middleware-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в моделе Юзера создаете метод

```
public function checkRole($role)
{
    if($this->role === $role) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Дальше в middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
  {
     if (Auth()::user->checkRole($role)) {
         return $next($request);
     }

     return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Permission denied');
  }
```